# just worked on a pinch gesture recognizer in swift 3 and can not figure out the following error

Tags: swift3, gesture

```
var width: CGFloat = 0
var height: CGFloat = 0
@IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!

@IBAction func zoomto(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

imageView1.frame = CGRect(imageView1.frame.origin.x, imageView1.frame.origin.y, width * sender.scale, height * sender.scale)
  }
```

showing an error "Argument labels '( _ :, _ :, _ :, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Any idea what needs to change to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use a valid `CGRect` constructor - see [the docs here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect).

In your case it would be something like :

```
CGRect(x: imageView1.frame.origin.x, y: imageView1.frame.origin.y, width: width * sender.scale, height: height * sender.scale)
```